# Grails <g:set tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, set

how to set grails variable in javascript?
I also tried

`<a onclick="myFunction(${aCase.id})" .../>`

`...`
`<script>`
`function myFunction(id) {`
`<g:set var="caseId" value="id"/>`
`}`
`</script>`

value of caseId always 'id' (string), i want it value of 'aCase.id'
thanks!
(sorry, i not good at english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set a gsp var with javascript. Cause the gsp var is set before the gsp is rendered on server side, and the javascript runs on client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>caseId = ${id}</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but it don't work, script not found 'caseId'

Comment: which version of Grails do you use?